# SharePoint report viewer error There are no addresses available for this application

Tags: sharepoint-server, error, 2016, reporting-services

i have single server (sql 2016 +all SharePoint 2016 role) when i click on a report to run (uploaded rdl file) SharePoint give me error There are no addresses available for this application

[image: error]

and in Manage Reporting Services Application when i click on system setting i got The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.

reconfiguration SSRS application dos not help

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is telling two things.

1. Check from the Central admin that "SQL Server Reporting Services Service" is started. `Central Admin > Application Management > Manage Services on Server`
2. Also check IIS and make sure all the related App Pools are started. 2nd error 503 means App pool stop.

Also check this document to make sure you did not miss any step: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-sharepoint/reporting-services-report-server-sharepoint-mode

Comment: tanks for answer
i check iis, all app pools are started include web service root and system
SQL Server Reporting Services Service was stopped i use Install-SPRSService 
to start service and i did it but the problem not resolve

Comment: check if App pool stoped again? also check the event log for the more clue

Comment: app pool started
but i use Set-SPServer SERVERNAME -Role Custom command, now i can start manually SSRS service in Services on Server (before that start action not available) but i got error Value cannot be null. Parameter name: name

Comment: where you get the value cannot be null?

Comment: when i try start "SQL Server Reporting Services Service" in Services on Server

Comment: one important issue. every time i reset iis "sharepoint web service root" (the app pool) is stopped

Comment: check the event log for clue( application, system or setup)